# Flex Mobile: app resizes when softkeyboard appears but doesn't resizes when it hides

Tags: android, apache-flex, resize, android-softkeyboard, flex-mobile

I have a Flex Mobile application, where my `ViewNavigatorApplication` is set to `resizeForSoftKeyboard="true"`. This, so that the View displayed resizes when the soft keyboard is called.

The view is increadibly simple. As you write on the `TextInput`, the items of a `List` will get filtered. So, when you click the `TextInput` the `softKeyboard` is raised and the application is resized to that you don't lose part of the screen. This works great but sometimes, when the `TextInput` loses its focus and the `softKeyboard` hides, the application won't resize back. This can be solved just by going to the previous `View` but it should not be happening.

Since I dont have enough reputation to attach an image, I hope you can go to the next link and see a screenshot that shows what I'm trying to explain:

[image]

Next is the code of the `View`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"        
                 xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                 xmlns:componets="componets.*"
                 xmlns:views="views.*">



    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:HTTPService id="getService"                                                                                                
                       requestTimeout="5"
                       method="GET"
                       result="getItemsHandler(event)"/>
        <s:HTTPService id="getItemService"                                                                                                
                       requestTimeout="5"
                       method="GET"
                       result="serviceReturned(event)"
                       fault="serviceReturned(event)"/>
    </fx:Declarations>



    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[               
            import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
            import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSONParseError;

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.core.IVisualElement;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            import singletons.AppConfiguration;
            import valueobjects.data.Contact;


            private var internalConfiguration:AppConfiguration = AppConfiguration.getInstance();                        


            override protected function createChildren():void
            {               
                super.createChildren();
                configureComponents();
                initializeList();
            }

            private function initializeList():void
            {
                if (internalConfiguration.Contacts != null)
                {
                    internalConfiguration.Contacts.filterFunction = filterList;
                    internalConfiguration.Contacts.refresh();
                }                               
                groupList.dataProvider = internalConfiguration.Contacts;                                                
            }                                   

            private function filterList(item:Object):Boolean
            {
                var contact:Contact = item as Contact;              
                var searchText:String = (contact.id + contact.name + contact.lastname).toLowerCase();
                searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();              
                var patern:String = filterText.text.toLowerCase();
                if (searchText.indexOf(patern) > -1)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

            /**
             * Handles the retrieved directory data and stores it.
             */
            private function getItemsHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                BLABLABLA...                
            }

            protected function contactSelected(event:MouseEvent):void
            {   
                if(groupList.selectedIndex == -1)
                {
                    return;
                }
                var person:Contact = groupList.selectedItem as Contact;
                getItemService.request.id = person.id;
                getItemService.request.name = person.name;          
                getItemService.send();              
                groupList.selectedItem = null;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:Group id="componentsGroup"
             width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Button id="backButton"                         
              click="backHandler()"/>   
        <s:TextInput id="filterText"                     
                     keyUp="internalConfiguration.Contacts.refresh()"/>
        <s:List id="groupList"              
                itemRenderer="components.renderers.ContactRenderer"
                click="contactSelected(event)"
                top="145" left="20" right="20" bottom="20">
        </s:List>
    </s:Group>  

</s:View>
```

I hope you can help me find why this is happening. It's incredibly annoying and I can't have that kind of behavior on the application. Any tip will be appreciated. 
Regards,

Sebastián

Comment: Same Problem with my appllication. have you get any solution?